# Inscrutable graphs of curves :Determine outer radius and inner radius for washer method

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the volume bounded by $x+y=3, y+x^2=3$, rotated about the line $x=2$

I graphed the function, but I couldn't tell which line was a greater distance from the line x=2. I don't know what the outer is.

How would you solve in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

In the picture it can be seen that the outer radius should be the line from  $2$ to $3$. However I would do this problem with shells.

Comment: are the linear lines usually further from the axis of revolution?